# How should I emphasize and style one word from js array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am just wondering if it is possible to bold one word from a given array element. My intention is to emphasize price information. I store elements in a variable to inform my clients about services.  Then I display these arrays elements in `li` elements in UI. Price bolding in HTML and CSS is not a problem. I wonder how to do it in JavaScript? Prices should be bolded and italicized.

```
const templates= ['Instagram templates & styling from $800 USD', 'Business/Loyalty Cards from $500 USD', 'Brand & Website Audit from $500 USD', 'Additional Web Pages $300 USD',
                 'Service Menu/Flyer from $1000 USD', 'Packaging design from $1000 USD', 'Price of website + online shop setup - from $4000 USD (up to 15 products)',
                 '+ SEO styler - $ 300 USD (implement basic SEO to any existing squarespace site)'];
```

```
const fourth = templates.map((templates, idx) => {
    return <li key={idx}>{templates}</li>
});
```

```
<div className="results">
   <div className="service-list">
      <h2 className="results">The kind of result you can expect</h2>
      <div>
         <ul className="mylist">
            <li>{fourth}</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input is trustworthy, you can match the prices with a regular expression and use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
const fourth = templates.map((str, idx) => {
    const __html = str.replace(/\$\s?\d+/g, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>`);
    return <li key={idx} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html }} />;
});
```

where the `highlight` class applies the styles you need.

A more elaborate method to split apart the string into React components with a conditional `className`:

```
const fourth = templates.map((str, idx) => {
    const matches = str.match(/\$\s?\d+|[^$]+/g);
    const children = matches.map(match => (
        match.startsWith('$')
            ? <span className="highlight">{match}</span>
            : <span>{match}</span>
    ));
    return <li key={idx}>{children}</li>;
});
```

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)